# selenium python for creating a instagram login liker bot

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I am using selenium for python to create a simple liker bot for instagram. The idea is to like the first photo of a tag (in this example is "sunset"). It correctly selects the first photo but does not insert a like.

The code is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from time import sleep

import User_data

chrome_options=Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
sleep(1)

browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(User_data.username)
browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(User_data.password)

sleep(1)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/button').click()

sleep(1)
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/sunset/")

sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//article/div[2]/div/div/div/a/div/div[2]").click()
sleep(1)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button/span[contains(@class. 'glyphsSpriteHeart__outline__24__grey_9 u-__7') ]").click()
```

Comment: Have you tried the xpath you get for the login button using the dev console? `//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/button`

Comment: Can you please wait specific element while page is loading after clicking the login button?

Comment: What happens when it tries to log in? Are you getting an error or ? If so, edit your question and add the full error message.

Comment: It worked with "//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/button" Thank you very much!

Comment: So my problem now, is to bypass the account verification afdter the log in, any ideas?

Comment: So i've updated it and now I want to create a simple liker bot for instagram. The idea is to like the first photo of a tag (in this example is "sunset"). It correctly selects the first photo but does not insert a like.

The code is as follows:

Comment: I'm not sure if you're still having problems with liking the post, but I'd recommend you to search the like button based on the aria-label instead of the class, since Instagram changes the class names every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're unable to Log In is because your code is unable to find the `element by xpath` you specified. That is probably because the xpath that you provide is not supported.

I have found a workaround for this where I use the function `find_elements_by_tag_name()` which returns me the list of buttons, and with simple iteration I found that the second button returned corresponds to the Log In button on Instagram. So here's a working code that you will find useful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from time import sleep

import User_data

chrome_options=Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")
sleep(1)

browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys(User_data.username)
browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys(User_data.password)

sleep(2)

buttons = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
for button_element in buttons:
    print(button_element.text)     #- This will print the text of the buttons present
```

This will print you the `text` fields of all the buttons:
**Output:**

```
Show
Log in
Log in with Facebook
```

These are the three buttons that come in my output, and since I have to click on the button with `Log in` in it's text, which is the second element from my list `buttons[]`, I use index 1 to denote that and click it.

```
buttons[1].click()
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, but it continues to not logging in, the only thing that it does is to show (unhide) the password.

Comment: @AlexandreBaptista that is because the button iteration in your case is different that it is in mine. I have updated my answer so that you can find which button to click. Kindly Check